# Definitions of ring and homomorphism of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Here we go again.

> My simple question is: does rings necessary have identity?

For example, authors like Rotman and Conrad assume that. But why is necessary to assume that a homomorphism of rings $f:A\rightarrow B$ has to have the condition $f(1_{A})=1_{B}$? I mean, what happens with the map $f(x)=0_{B}$ for all $x\in A$? I think this should be a homomorphism of rings but with the extra condition we'd have $B=\{0\}$.

Comment: Short answer is that [it varies between authors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)#Notes_on_the_definition).

Comment: As @πr8 says, different people use different definitions. Each definition is more convenient for some things and less convenient for others. One also uses the term rng for things that are like rings but don't (necessarily) have multiplicative identities. [That is of course if one's definition of rings requires a multiplicative identity.]

Comment: @charter If it did not occur to you that there might *not* be an absolute convention that everybody follows, then learn it well now. Terms and conventions are not always universally agreed upon.

Comment: @rschwieb but this is mathematics and I think the definitions should be clear and very precise. For example for groups there is no such ambiguity. That's why I found this about rings some unsatisfactory.

Comment: @Charter Nevertheless, not everything is writ in stone (thank goodness). It is just a fact of life, and finding it unacceptable is fine to some extent, although futile.

Comment: @Charter Also: there is a big difference between giving clear definitions and having universally used definitions.

Answer (score 2):

No, rings do not necessarily have identity, for example  $2\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring in most cases. Some authors do say it however demands it, most from my experience do not simply because it makes it more difficult to work with.

As for your homomorphism, it has to have that condition because it's an inevitable consequence, if the ring has identity then
$$f(1\cdot a)=f(a)=f(1)\cdot f(a)$$
so clearly we must have $f(1)=1$ for this to be true.

Comment: $f\colon x \mapsto 0$ is also multiplicative. And if one does not require ring homomorphisms to be unital, then $f(1)$ can also be a nontrivial idempotent.

Comment: @ZelosMalum, We have $f(a)=f(1).f(a)$ only for $f(a)\in Im(f)$, not for every element in $B$. It will require that $f$ be surjective but this is not the general case. I think if we assumme rings have identity then $Im(f)$ is a subring of B and $f(1)=1_{Im(f)}$. Note we do not impose that a subring of $B$ has the same identity of $B$.